# R : Run while loop until all elements of a vector are less than a threshold

Tags: r, loops, vector, while-loop, logical-operators

In R, I want my while loop to continue until each element in a particular vector 'theta_diff' (which is updated in the while loop in each iteration) reduces below a particular threshold 'epsilon'.
Presently I am able to achieve this by using an OR condition in the while loop test condition (theta_diff is a 2-element vector):

```
while((theta_diff[1]>epsilon)|(theta_diff[2]>epsilon))
{
  }
```

I am wondering if there is a smarter way to do this? I tried the all() but it implements a AND logic instead of an OR logic and so even if one of the theta_diff elements meet the criteria, the while loop stops.

```
while(all(theta_diff>epsilon))
{
  }
```

Main inspiration to search for a smarter option is that: depending upon the program, the dimension of the theta_diff vector may change and I want to make the while loop condition independent of the length of the theta_diff vector.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I could come up with two options (at least one element of `theta_diff` is greater than `epsilon`):

- `any(theta_diff > epsilon)`
- `max(theta_diff) > epsilon`

Similarly, the following two are equivalent (all elements of `theta_diff` are greater than `epsilon`):

- `all(theta_diff > epsilon)`
- `min(theta_diff) > epsilon`

---

Sometimes using `repeat` is more readable than using `while`. Why not consider:

```
repeat {
  ## blablabla
  if (all(theta_diff > epsilon)) break
  }
```

which means ***do ... until ...***.